# R parallel - functions gives only intialmatrix back

Tags: r, parallel-processing

i try to check from a data.frame row by row if the elements from one row are identical.

My real dataset contains over 1 million rows and several columns of negative and positive numbers, as well as 0 and NAs. In total there are 15 datasets I want to examine, hence the parallel variant.

Unfortunately my current code gives me only the initial matrix. Since I have never worked with the "paralel" package I don't know some much about it. I tried to use the "clusterExport" argument, but so far nothing helped.

Therefore the question where my mistake is and the request for help.

Many thanks in advance.

```r
x_x <- data.frame("x"=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),10),"y"=rep(c(1,2,3,2,1,NA,7,8,9,10),10),"z"=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),10))

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

Test_parallel2 <- function(data_01)
{
  # data_01 <- x_x
  return_data <- data.frame("V1"=matrix(FALSE,nrow = nrow(data_01),ncol = 1))
  data_01 <- as.data.frame(t(data_01))

  is_true_eigen <- function(data_vec)
  {
    # data_vec <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
    return_data_is_true <- TRUE
    for(i in 1:length(data_vec))
    {
      if(data_vec[i] == FALSE)
      {
        return_data_is_true <- FALSE
        break(i)
      }
    }
    return(return_data_is_true)
  }
  
  y <- foreach(i=1:ncol(data_01)) %dopar% {
    
    if( (data_01[1,i] == data_01[2,i]) == TRUE & ( mean(as.numeric(data_01[,i]),na.rm = TRUE) == data_01[1,i]) & ( is_true_eigen(colSums(!is.na(t(data_01[,i]))) > 0) == TRUE ) ) 
    {
      return_data[i,1] <- TRUE  # i=1
    }
    
  }
  
  #parallel::clusterExport(cl = cl,varlist = c("y"),envir=environment())
  
  return(return_data)
  
}

Test_parallel2(x_x)
```

Edit:

The output should be a vector for each row with true or false (if row elements are identical)

example:

Row1 (from x_x):

1 | 1 | 1

should return one TRUE

Row4 (from x_x):

4 | 2 | 4

should return one FALSE

Row6 (from x_x):

6 | NA | 6

should return one FALSE

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re trying to do. Could you give us an example of the output you’d be expecting to get from your x_x sample data input?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added it. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no-one else has chimed in I've had a go at this one. I don't use the  *foreach* or *doParallel* packages in my day-to-day work or hobby projects, so I've reverted to my go-to method for parallelisation, which is the *parallel* package.

I've done this using three parallelisation schemes: serial (no parallelisation), fork threading (Unix-like systems only) and PSOCK (Windows & Unix-like systems).

To do this without any parallelisation we could define the following function:

```r
#####################
### Serial Method ###
#####################

### row_equal() ###
row_equal <- function(data){
  
  ## Transpose Data ##
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  
  ## Apply Function Internals ##
  n <- lapply(
    X = data,
    FUN = unique
  )
  
  ## Number of Unique Values ##
  n <- lengths(n, use.names = FALSE)
  
  ## Convert to Output to Logical ##
  eq <- ifelse(n == 1L, TRUE, FALSE)
  
  ## Output ##
  return(eq)
  
}
```

To parallelise the `row_equal()` function using fork threading, we could modify it to the following:

```r
##############################
### Parallel (FORK) Method ###
##############################

### row_equal_fork() ###
row_equal_fork <- function(data){
  
  ## Transpose Data ##
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  
  ## Cores ##
  n_cores <- max(parallel::detectCores() - 1L, 1L)
  
  ## Apply Function Internals ##
  n <- parallel::mclapply(
    X = data,
    FUN = unique,
    mc.cores = n_cores
  )
  
  ## Number of Unique Values ##
  n <- lengths(n, use.names = FALSE)
  
  ## Convert to Output to Logical ##
  eq <- ifelse(n == 1L, TRUE, FALSE)
  
  ## Output ##
  return(eq)
  
}
```

Unfortunately, the simple fork-threading version only works on Unix-like systems. Windows can't do it. For Windows we need to set up a PSOCK cluster, pass it the job we want it to do, then stop the cluster upon completion/failure. In this case, the job is quite simple, but for more complicated jobs you may need to use `parallel::clusterEvalQ()` to pass the cluster required packages, or `parallel::clusterExport()` to pass the cluster additional objects.

To parallelise the `row_equal()` function using a PSOCK cluster, we could modify it to the following:

```r
###############################
### Parallel (PSOCK) Method ###
###############################

### row_equal_psock() ###
row_equal_psock <- function(data){
  
  ## Transpose Data ##
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  
  ## Cores ##
  n_cores <- max(parallel::detectCores() - 1L, 1L)
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores, type = "PSOCK")
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))
  
  ## Apply Function Internals ##
  n <- parallel::parLapply(
    cl = cl,
    X = data,
    fun = unique
  )
  
  ## Number of Unique Values ##
  n <- lengths(n, use.names = FALSE)
  
  ## Convert to Output to Logical ##
  eq <- ifelse(n == 1L, TRUE, FALSE)
  
  ## Output ##
  return(eq)
  
}
```

In the case of your test data frame (`x_x`) I got the following output when using the functions:

```
row_equal(x_x)
##  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [13]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## [25] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [37]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## [49]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [61]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [73]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## [85] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [97]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

All versions of the function give the same output:

```r
identical(row_equal(x_x), row_equal_fork(x_x))
## [1] TRUE
identical(row_equal(x_x), row_equal_psock(x_x))
## [1] TRUE
```

However, note that parallelising a function will not necessarily make it run faster, as there are overheads associated with both methods of parallelisation; particularly with the PSOCK method (on my crappy ARM64 laptop, anyway):

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  serial = row_equal(x_x),
  parallel_fork = row_equal_fork(x_x),
  parallel_psock = row_equal_psock(x_x),
  times = 100L
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
##          serial   2.425209   5.059251    6.211456    5.545606    6.358625   21.22458   100
##   parallel_fork  76.978126  92.248626  113.667318  117.062001  127.628751  166.58804   100
##  parallel_psock 949.944959 990.536689 1014.325810 1009.042293 1036.322251 1120.35083   100
```

If you data set contains many rows, then you may start to see some benefit from the parallel methods. The purist in me feels the slight niggle that there must be a vectorized way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I've tried it immediately and your serial method worked perfect.

It is impressive to see how the 3 variants perform over time. To be honest, I did not expect that. Thanks and greetings